# Assigning the value of a table row ID with another ID using an SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

So in my database i have two tables. Jokes and Comments. I want the ability to assign the post_id of the comment, to the joke_id of the joke, so it will assign and retrieve the comments relating to that joke. My problem is that i suck at writing SQL statements and haven't the foggiest on how to join two tables to make this happen.

My jokes table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jokes` (
  `joke_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `joke` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vote` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`joke_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

and my comments table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `joke_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

and for the moment, I am grabbing the data by assigned the $post_id = "1", but i want to change it to something like $post_id = $joke_id (with the joke id being in the same function, but i have no idea how to do it).

I'm using a MVC with codeigniter if thats any help.

Inside my controller, i have a php file called comments which has a function called insertComment, which looks like this:

```
public function insertComment(){

//extracts the data from the ajax
extract($_POST);
if($_POST['act'] == 'add-com'){
    //assigned the db rows with the actual data which was inputted
    $data = array(
        'name' => htmlentities($name),
        'comment' => htmlentities($comment),
        //id_post should correlate to the joke_id
        'id_post' => $id_post = "1"

        );


    $this->comments_m->insertComment($data);
}
```

and my insertComment function, inside the models of comment_m function looks like this:

```
function insertComment (){

extract($_POST);
if($_POST['act'] == 'add-com'){
    $data = array(
        'name' => htmlentities($name),
        'comment' => htmlentities($comment),
        'id_post' => $id_post = "1"

    );

    if(strlen($data['name']) <= '1'){
        $data['name'] = 'Guest';
    }

    $this->db->insert('comments', $data);
}
}
```

To finalise, it would be a great help if someone could help with an SQL statement which joins the two tables together, which the joke_id having the same value as the comment's post_id which will make it unique to that joke.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The SQL to join these two tables is -

```
SELECT `jokes`.*, `comments`.*
FROM `jokes`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments`
ON `jokes`.`joke_id` = `comments`.`joke_id`
```

This will return all of the comments for each joke. You can then filter or limit by adding the WHERE clause(s) -

```
WHERE `jokes`.`joke_id` = 1
```

Comment: Just a note, this will return each joke repeated for each comment on the joke.

Comment: True, at that point you can filter for display. You could also do a sub-select, but that would not be as fast.